# How do i place canvas_text in a grid so that i could use a background image and place text on it

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I'm trying to place a canvas_text in a grid. So that it doesn't merge with other widgets when i run the program in a different resolution.

```py
from tkinter import *
admn=Tk()
canvas=Canvas(admn,height=600,width=600)
tx1=canvas.create_text(text='try',font="Calibri",20),fill='orange').grid(column=10,row=5)
canvas.pack()
admn.mainloop()
```

I get an  tuple index out of range error message when i run the above code

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `grid` on items on a canvas. If you're placing things on a canvas, you are required to do all of the math to put it where you want it. That's not the only problem in the code, but that's the main problem you're asking about.

Comment: Is there any other way i could do it?. Let me explain you my problem, i'm actually working on another project using canvas cause i want to add an background image and use canvas text so that the background of the text is transparent unlike the annoying white background in labels. When i run the same project in a different resolution, widgets overlap on each other..is there any other way i could solve this issue?

Comment: @AnikethS: there's no way I can properly answer that in the comments. The short answer is "no". If you use a canvas, you have to do all of the math for laying out objects. Tkinter gives you all the tools you need (for example, the ability to figure out how many pixels are in a string), but you have to do the work yourself. There's nothing like `pack` or `grid` for canvas items.